# On Gitlab, is there a way to allow Maintaners to merge MRs even if some checks fail?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We would like to allow Maintainers to be able to merge some MRs, even if checks in the pipeline for the MR fail. Developers should not be able to do the same thing.

I see there is a way to skip a pipeline run, and to allow merge of MRs with skipped pipelines, but there does not seem to be a way to control who can skip the pipeline run.

There are custom approval rules, but you cannot make a custom approval rule conditional, so if we added a rule that had all Maintainers they would ALWAYS have to approve all MRs, and I don't think it would override the "require pipeline success" cofiguration.

I do not see a way to achieve what we want without allowing all developers to skip pipelines and merge. Am I missing something?